# Inserting probabilities in a card game

Tags: javascript, image, random

I'm looking to create a code in which a card would be drawn randomly by pressing a button. However, I would like some cards to be rarer than others, but I don't know how to integrate this, the code is not at all my favorite domain ...
Thank you very much for your help and the tips you can give me!

```
    var spongebob = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/spongebob.png'>";
var patrick = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/patrick.png'>";
var squidward = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/squidward.png'>";
var sandy = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/sandy.png'>";
var krabs = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/krabs.png'>";
var larry = "<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/larry.png'>";
var images = [spongebob, patrick, squidward, sandy, krabs, larry]
var names = ["Spongebob Squarepants", "Patrick Star", "Squidward Tentacles", "Sandy Cheeks", "Eugene Krabs", "Larry Lobster"]
function displayImage(){
  var rn = Math.random();
  rn = rn*6;
  rn = Math.floor(rn);
  document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML=images[rn];
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=names[rn];
}
```

Comment: Hello!  have you thought about putting the same image in the array multiple times?  The images in the array fewer times would be 'rarer'.  Thanks for getting that theme song stuck in my head again, btw.

Comment: I thought about it ! But isn't there a way to do this more "cleanly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is called a Weighted Random selection, that is to say it is still a random selection, but some items are weighted higher. The algorithm is fairly simple.

You start with a list of items, and you assign each one a relative weight. The higher the weight, the more likely it is to be picked. Then, pick a random number between 0 and the *total weight of all items* and you step through the items subtracting each items weight from the random number you selected. when the number reaches zero, you have your item.

Heres an example.

```js
function WeightedBroker(){
    this.totalWeight = 0;
    this.items = [];
    
    this.addItem = function(value,weight){
       this.items.push({value,weight});
       this.totalWeight+= weight;
    }
    
    this.pickItem = function(){
       var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalWeight);
       for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++){
           if(rnd<=this.items[i].weight)
              return this.items[i].value;
           rnd -= this.items[i].weight;
       }
    }
}

var broker = new WeightedBroker();
broker.addItem("a",100);
broker.addItem("b",10);
broker.addItem("c",1);

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
   console.log(broker.pickItem());
```

Applying this to your code is pretty easy, you will want to change those 2 arrays (one with img html, and one with names) to objects containing the properties `name` and `src`. You add each of these items to the broker I wrote above with appropriate weights for each according to your requirement. Something like this:

```js
function WeightedBroker(){
    this.totalWeight = 0;
    this.items = [];

    this.addItem = function(value,weight){
       this.items.push({value,weight});
       this.totalWeight+= weight;
    }

    this.pickItem = function(){
       var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.totalWeight);
       for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++){
           if(rnd<=this.items[i].weight)
              return this.items[i].value;
           rnd -= this.items[i].weight;
       }
    }
}

var broker = new WeightedBroker();
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/spongebob.png'>",name:"Spongebob Squarepants"},100);
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/patrick.png'>",name:"Patrick Star"},100);
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/squidward.png'>",name:"Squidward Tentacles"},100);
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/sandy.png'>",name:"Sandy Cheeks"},100);
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/krabs.png'>",name:"Eugene Krabs"},100);
broker.addItem({src:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/larry.png'>",name:"Larry Lobster"},100);

var item = broker.pickItem();
document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML=item.src;
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=item.name;
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="pic"></div>
```

Comment: I will try to put this into practice, thank you! How can I make sure there is only one to draw?

Comment: I actually like this solution better than mine.  Its much prettier.  Nice work!

Comment: Hm, I tried to apply this for my code, but I can't, I apologize

Comment: @SuperSaumon no need to apologise, what specific problem were you having?

Comment: It's absolutely perfect, everything works as I want thanks to you ! Thanks a lot for your help and thank you very much also Nibb !

Answer (score 0):

instead of having the array just have images do something like the following (where a low number in 'rarity' means more rare:

```
  var spongebob = {
    url:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/spongebob.png'>",
    rarity: 1
  };

  var patrick = {
    url:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/patrick.png'>",
    rarity: 2
  };
  var squidward = {
    url:"<img src = 'http://www.homastudio.com/img/squidward.png'>",
    rarity: 4
  };
  var images = [spongebob, patrick, squidward];

  var imageChoiceArr = [];

  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    image = images[i];
    for(var ii=0;ii<image.rarity;ii++) {
      imageChoiceArr.push(image.url);
    }
  }
```

Then pick randomly from the 'imageChoiceArr'